# Function matching "Z" shaped graph, for given data pattern

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of data that can be described like this:

For positive integer $n$

$x-2n$ from $x=0$ through $x=n$

$2x-3n$ from $x=n$ through $x=2n$

$x-n$ from $x=0$ through $x=3n$

The values I'm trying to match:

$n=1$: $-2, -2, 1$

$n=2$: $-4, -3, -2, 0, 2, 3$

$n=3$: $-6, -5, -4, -3, -1, 1, 3, 4, 5$

I'm very close (I think) with a three-part equation that's giving me the correct slope for first and third segment. I just can't seem to identify which variables are controlling which areas.

$$\frac{\left|\left(2x+1n\ -a\right)\right|-\left|\left(2x-a\right)\right|+2\left(x-a\right)\ }{2} + 2n$$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/socvbwbit1

[image]

I do know that the $2(x-a)$ is creating the slope for the first and third segments. $a$ is just $3.5n$, and controls "vertical" placement. This just doesn't quite have the right slope on the middle segment and is driving me bonkers.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out! Yay me! Getting ice cream for this one:

$a\ =2n$

$$\frac{\left|\left(x+n\ -a\right)\right|-\left|\left(x-a\right)\right|+2\left(x-a\right)\ }{2}+\frac{n}{2}$$

This can probably be simplified but I feel like a real boy having figured it out at all! Thanks everyone